# Run PS2 eyetoy camera on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: video, webcam, sony

What do I need to do to connect a Sony PS2 eyetoy camera to a Dell laptop (Ubuntu 14.04) or a Pandaboard (Ubuntu 12.04)?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this website](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/playstation-eyetoy-windows-ubuntu-mac/), that camera will work out of the box. You should just be able to plug it in and use it.

You can test it out by installing the program Cheese, available from the Ubuntu Software Center.

A [more recent post (2014)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471732/ps2-eyetoy-recording-quality) states that the camera works perfectly fine on 12.04.

Comment: Ah, regrettably not.  I have tried it in two environments.  On a Pandaboard running 12.04, cheese core dumps with both the eyetoy and a 'normal' Logitech webcam.  On a new Dell lap-top running 14.04, /dev/video1 shows up for both cameras, cheese finds and runs the Logitech camera, but won't recognize the eyetoy.  I'm thinking it's because the eyetoy puts out only jpeg images.  So are there any hard-core C solutions?

Comment: @dms489 I only know the very basics of C and drivers, so I can't help you in that case. I'm sorry.

Comment: I saw somewhere a recommendation to use the openCV libraries, so I did.  The process was painstaking especially since I have three different hosts, but the results are extraordinary.  Now, a program about 10 lines long read either camera and show them in real-time as good quality moving images.

Comment: Back to Square 1.  In rebuilding my system (sad story deleted) I now find that openCV doesn't work by the previous process.  Got to find a simpler way to read an image from my EyeToy

Answer (score 1):

I know you didn't ask about Ubuntu 16.04, but I can confirm that the PS2 Eyetoy camera works out-of-the-box on that version. I checked to see if it was detected with:

```
lsusb
```

which returned:

```
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 054c:0155 Sony Corp.
```

and then used Cheese Webcam Booth to test the picture.

PS. These cameras have a manual focus ring on the front, took me a while to realise.